# chromiun gn exceptions disabled

Tags: c++, chromium

```
error: cannot use `throw` with exceptions disabled
    throw std::domain_error("Mask value out of range");
```

I used an exception in my code，then, how can I enable exceptions in chromium, who can help me, thank you

Comment: You can't. Don't use exceptions in your code.

Comment: "throw" can not use? but libc use "throw",I find "throw" in "locale.h"

Answer (score 1):

If you compile on windows, you chould modify the configuration of compiler.Add "/EHsc" on cflags.